# Advanced screen scraping?

Tags: java, image, screen, screen-scraping, processing

I saw several websites for game robots to be used on games on yahoo, pogo, etc. what do you use/how do you write software that detects items on the screen? How do you get, for example in java, to detect the dynamic game window and recognize that a square block is at play (for example in tetris).. how do you make the leap from item on screen to getting software to recognize it??

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, in Java/Processing, you normally would embed an Applet in a website. The Java Frame class gives you a screen XY starting point (the top left corner, ie. 0,0) and a screen bounds (the bottom right corner, ie. 'width' and 'height'). This is similar to Python, JavaScript, and any other software - web or otherwise - works with a 'canvas' ie. a screen.

Secondly, whatever you are drawing to the screen is of your own creation - so you programatically have access to the XY coordinates of whatever you draw. This can be controlled by global variables, or better yet, an Object of a Class with methods to return the coordinates.

Example:

```
Ball ball;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  smooth();

  ball = new Ball(width/2, height/2, 60);
}

void draw() {
  background(0, 255, 0);
  ball.move();
  ball.boundsDetect();
  ball.draw();

  println("The X Position is " + getX() + " and the Y Position is " + getY());
}

class Ball {

  float x, y;
  float xSpeed = 2.8;
  float ySpeed = 2.2;
  int bSize, bRadius;
  int xDirection = 1;
  int yDirection = 1;

  Ball(int _x, int _y, int _size) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    bSize = _size;
    bRadius = bSize/2;
  } 

  void move() {
    x = x + (xSpeed * xDirection);
    y = x + (ySpeed * yDirection);
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(x, y, bSize, bSize); 
    println("here");
  }

  void boundsDetect() {
    if (x > width - bRadius || x < bRadius) {
      xDirection *= -1;
    }
    if (y > height - bRadius || y < bRadius) {
      yDirection *= -1;
    }

  }

  float getX() {
    return x;
  }

  float getY() {
    return y;
  }

}
```